# Parsing UTF-8 encoded binary Android Manifest XML

Tags: javascript, android, android-manifest

I'm having issues with npm package node-apk-parser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-apk-parser), which parses Android binary manifest file. I have a binary manifest file. The library thinks, that this file is encoded using UTF-8 encoding (it reads 32 bytes at specific offset and ANDs it with 0b100000000 and if this doesn't return 0, it thinks, that the file is encoded in UTF-8)

```
header.flags = this.readU32(); // reads 32 bits at current offset
... // other code
encoding = header.flags & StringFlags.UTF8 ? 'utf-8' : 'ucs2';
```

Then it tries to read through strings in the file. The way it does that is, that it reads one byte, that supposedly represents length of word as integer number of characters. Then it reads another byte, which apparently represents length of the same word in bytes (since single character in UTF-8 can be represented by multiple bytes, so the two lengths might be different).

The problematic part of this however is, what happens if length of the word is more than 255 characters (or bytes depending on which of the two above mentioned bytes it's currently looking at).

The function to read value of the length-byte is following:

```
BinaryXmlParser.prototype.readLength8 = function() {
  var len;
  len = this.readU8();
  if (len & 0x80) {
    len = (len & 0x7f) << 7;
    len += this.readU8();
  }
  return len;
}
```

This obviously means, that if the length-byte has stored value larger than 127 (an 8bit number), it will left shift the value ANDed by 0x&F by 7 bits. In my manifest file, for a specific position in the file, the value for the length-bit that I get is 0xFF. This value being ANDed to 0x7F is 0x7F. Left shifting by 7 bits leads to 0x3F80. Then we read next byte and add it to this value. However, 0x3F80 is already a very large number and in my case it means, that the code is trying to read string beyond length of the whole file.

Therefore my suspicion is, that this code is not correct. However, since I can't find any specification of the UTF-8 encoded Android binary xml format, I don't know if the code really is not correct, and even if it is, I have no idea how should lengths of words greater than 255 be handled.

Has anybody encountered this issue before? Thank you for help.